# Count row with month and other condition

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I know we can count rows easily, but i have some problem doing that.

[image: this is my table]

I tried to count row where the value is not equal to '-' in each month. This query below counts all row in all months.

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(tanggal) as bulan,
(SELECT COUNT(iad) FROM triwulan WHERE iad!='-') as iadp,
(SELECT COUNT(isk) FROM triwulan WHERE isk!='-') as isk,
(SELECT COUNT(vap) FROM triwulan WHERE vap!='-') as vap,
(SELECT COUNT(hap) FROM triwulan WHERE hap!='-') as hap,
(SELECT COUNT(plebitis) FROM triwulan WHERE plebitis!='tidak') as plebitis
FROM `triwulan`
group by bulan
```

I would appreciate any help, thank you..

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design. Consider having one `infection_type` column, with a row for each infection type.

Comment: Besides, if someone recovers from isk, but still has vap, how would you even record that with the current schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to comments, an example of a normalised design *might* look like this:

```
examination 
examination_id tanggal    
             1 2019-02-01 
             2 2019-02-02 
             3 2019-02-03 
             4 2019-03-01 

examination_detail
examination_id infection_type plebitis
             1 iad            iya
             1 hap            iya
             2 hap            tidak
             3 isk            iya
             3 vap            iya
             4 isk            tidak
             4 vap            tidak
```

You'd have to decide whether plebitis more properly belongs in the examination table or the detail table.